# Optional one-to-one mapping in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, one-to-one

How do I create an optional one-to-one mapping in the hibernate hbm file? For example, suppose that I have a User and a last_visited_page table. The user may or may not have a last_visited page. Here is my current one-to-one mapping in the hbm file:

User Class:

```
<one-to-one name="lastVisitedPage" class="LastVisitedPage" cascade="save-update">
```

LastVisitedPage Class:

```
<one-to-one name="user" class="user" constrained="true" />
```

The above example does not allow the creation of a user who does not have a last visited page. A freshly created user has not visited any pages yet. How do I change the hbm mapping to make the userPrefs mapping optional?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To my knowledge, Hibernate doesn't support optional one-to-one (see [HHH-2007](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2007)) so you'll have to use a fake `many-to-one` with `not-null="false"` instead.

Comment: is that still true in 2018?

Comment: JPA 2.1 appears to support optional OneToOne, see [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742542/hibernate-jpa-optional-one-to-one-bidirectional-mapping), or the [documentation.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html)

Comment: When I do this it does not reference the other table even though I'm explicitly specifying the class in the tag. it does successfully when it's one to one however, but does not let me insert only update...

Comment: I just get "unknown column" errors from this conversion from one-to-one to many-to-one.

Answer (score 15):

Just spend most of the day today trying to do a similar thing, finally found the following solution (just in-case this might be useful for other people)

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ClassA_Id", referencedColumnName="ClassB_Id", nullable=true)
```

Hope that might help save somebody some time

Comment: Just an FYI - this workaround has issues if you use Envers (you'll get this error: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3853). Hibernate 3.6.8 has fixed the issue with an optional @OneToOne mapping though.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue, resolved with `@OneToOne(optional = true)` on the User class (hibernate 5.2.17.Final)

Comment: [JPA API docs here.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html)

Answer (score 7):

I was having a simliar problem, but using annotations.  Google brought me here, so if anyone else finds themselves in the same sitatuions, this worked for me:

http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/ANN-725

If you're using annotations, you can use the @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE) annotation so that you don't get an exception.  Just make sure your code checks for nulls because it's now might not be there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If a user has at most one last_visited page, then there are two cases :

(a) some given user has no last_visited page, in which case there will not be any tuple for this user in the last_visited_page table,
(b) some given user has exactly one last_visited page, in which case there will be exactly one tuple for this user in the last_visited_page table.

That should make it obvious that userid is a candidate key in your last-visited-page table.

And that should make it obvious that you should declare that key to the DBMS.