# Hibernate two foreign keys on same table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I would have a **Teacher** entity that has ManyToOne relationship on **School**. That's for another use case, where teacher can join to an existing school, meaning a school can have many teachers, but there needs to be one owner, the creator or the admin of that particular school.

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class Teacher extends User {

  @JoinColumn(name = "school_id")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private School school;
```

**School entity**

```
@Entity
public class School extends BaseEntity {

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "school")
  private Set<Teacher> teachers;
```

This works. What would now be the proper way to add an owner column to the **School** entity. Owner would be the id of the teacher that created that school. It is only assigned once during the creation of the school.

So when adding a new teacher I choose to create new school by assigning a name to it. When school is created I would assign this same teacher persisted ID as the owner for that created school.

Adding an extra OneToOne on School entity seems to work at first, but now it's impossible to break the FK relationship between these 2 tables.

**Added to school**

```
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "owner_teacher_id")
  private Teacher owner;
```

For persisting I would be doing something like this, and it works with the current relationship, but I think it's wrong, is there any easier way to set the creator of the record?

```
Teacher savedTeacher = teacherRepository.save(teacher);
School savedSchool = schoolService.saveSchool(school);

savedTeacher.setSchool(savedSchool);

if (schoolForm.isNewSchool())
  savedSchool.setOwner(savedTeacher);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `any easier way`? You have to set the relationship somehow, and there's only two setter calls there.

Comment: The service works, that's how it should be I feel like, but the relationship is not right. If I were to change the schema, I cannot drop either 'school' nor 'teacher' tables not through hbm2ddl => create-drop or even manually. I have to drop the whole schema because both tables have a reference to one another.

Comment: You have two relationships causing a chicken and egg senario when you try to drop tables.  Drop the constraints first, then the table and you won't have problems.  But there doesn't seem to be anything unreasonable with what you are doing - it is what is intended isn't it?  My only concern is with the orphan removal setting - do you really intend that the owner is deleted from the database when a school is deleted?  Closing a school means that teacher no longer owns the school, but I don't see why you'd want the remove cascaded to all teachers as well.

Comment: As for easier ways, you have the cascade settings set, so all you need to use is em.merge on the school and JPA will figure out the inserts/updates for you.  Set your relationships upfront and then you only need to merge the school.

Comment: To circumvent the circular dependency, you could also model it on the teacher's side: As a `@OneToOne(optional=true)` (I am not sure on how far hibernate is with [this bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2007), but there are also [workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2784668/592355)) ...and I agree with Chris' "cascading considerations".

Comment: Yes the cascading is not intentional, I just quickly pulled the code, no worries there I won't delete the school when teacher leaves ;) @Chris well problem with current solution is that it slows down the development if I would have to drop constraints first, haven't seen Hibernate is that smart. I am just worried of the circular relation, will look into swapping things around.

Comment: I don't know hibernate's DDL, but EclipseLink's DDL generation does attempt to drop constraints before the tables.  If it is a problem, just write your own drop table script to run when needed.  DDL generation is just meant to aid in development; problems with it should not justify model changes that would go into production.