# Optional one to one relationship - hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, one-to-many, one-to-one

This is about as simple as it gets - A company (Company table) **can** have a PIA agreement (PIA table) but **isn't required** to have one. I have tried the entire day searching all over stack overflow and google with different wording and still cannot find a solution that works for SELECT, INSERT, **AND** UPDATE. I found some half-decent documentation on one-to-one vs many-to-one in Hibernate, but the examples are very vague. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html search this text "5.1.13. One-to-one"

create_company.sql

```
CREATE TABLE company (
    id SMALLINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(60) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

create_pia.sql

```
CREATE TABLE pia (
    company_id smallint,
    agreement_number varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY  (company_id),
    CONSTRAINT pia_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company (id)
);
```

---

Note: It seems `cascade="all"` was needed to get UPDATE to work.

**When I use this:**

```
<one-to-one name="pia" class="something.something.Pia" cascade="all"/>
```

SELECT and UPDATE both work, but **INSERT Fails** with this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`iti101088_15112`.`pia`, CONSTRAINT `pia_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`))
```

**When I use this:**

```
<many-to-one name="pia" class="something.something.Pia" cascade="all"/>
```

I get this when fetching the company:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'company0_.pia' in 'field list'
```

**When I use this:**

```
<many-to-one name="pia" class="something.something.Pia" cascade="all" property-ref="companyId"/>
```

I get the same error when fetching the company:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'company0_.pia' in 'field list'
```

**When I use this:**

```
<many-to-one name="pia" class="something.something.Pia" cascade="all" property-ref="companyId" column="id"/>
```

I get `NullPointerException` when fetching the company???????????

**When I use the suggestion** from here `Hibernate doesn't support optional one-to-one (see HHH-2007) so you'll have to use a fake many-to-one with not-null="false" instead`
[Optional one-to-one mapping in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784228/optional-one-to-one-mapping-in-hibernate)

```
<many-to-one name="pia" class="something.something.Pia" cascade="all" not-null="false"/>
```

I get this familiar error when fetching the company:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'company0_.pia' in 'field list'
```

**When I tweak it a little bit as such**:

```
<many-to-one name="pia" class="something.something.Pia" cascade="all">
    <column name="id" not-null="false"/>
</many-to-one>
```

I get this very strange error:

```
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy [something.something.Pia#1] - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy [something.something.Pia#1] - no Session (through reference chain: something.something.Company["pia"]->something.something.Pia$HibernateProxy$54WqyDsD["agreementNumber"])
```

---

**The code**

Company.hbm.xml

```
<class name="something.something.Company" table="COMPANY">
    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="NAME"/>
    <many-to-one name="pia" class="something.something.Pia" cascade="all"/>
</class>
```

Pia.hbm.xml

```
<class class="something.something.Pia" table="PIA">
    <id name="companyId" column="COMPANY_ID"/>
    <property name="agreementNumber" column="AGREEMENT_NUMBER"/>
</class>
```

Company.java

```
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Company() { }
    public Company(int id, String name, Pia pia) {
        //I have no idea if this even does anything
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        Pia companyPia = pia;
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public Pia getPia() { return pia; }
    public void setPia(Pia pia) { this.pia = pia; }
}
```

Pia.java

```
public class Pia implements Serializable {
    private int companyId;
    private String agreementNumber;
    
    public Pia() { }
    public Pia(int companyId, String agreementNumber) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
        this.agreementNumber = agreementNumber;  
    }

    public int getCompanyId() { return companyId; }
    public void setCompanyId(int companyId) { this.companyId = companyId; }

    public String getAgreementNumber() { return agreementNumber; }
    public void setAgreementNumber(String agreementNumber) { this.agreementNumber = agreementNumber; }
}
```

SELECT statement execution java code:

```
@Override
public Company findCompanyByCompanyId(int companyId) {
    return (Company) DataAccessUtils.singleResult(template.find("from Company where id=?0", companyId));
}
```

INSERT statement execution java code:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public int insertCompany(Company company) {
    int result = -1;
    try {
        template.save(company);
        result = company.getId();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

UPDATE statement execution java code:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public int updateCompany(Company myCompany) {
    int result = 0;
    try {
        template.update(myCompany);
        result = 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        result = -1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's what you get when you read documentation for versions that are more than 15 years old. Here is the current documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one

Instead of googling and looking on stack overflow, try the official project website https://hibernate.org where you can find all the information you need. As for your model, it's pretty simple. This is all you need:

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Pia pia;
}

@Entity
public class Pia {
    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    private Company company;
    private String agreementNumber;
}
```

Comment: I am using a .xml file, not annotations... how can I configure this to work using the mapping file (as seen above: Company.hbm.xml)?

Comment: Again, you'll find all of that information in the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e4865

Comment: That documentation only deals with the situation where you have an extra column `parent_id`  (besides Pk) in the client table. If you want to share the same Pk in both tables (like is the case in this question) it simply doesn't work with optional in my experience. Hibernate will *always* throw an `EntityNotFoundException` if the related entity does not exist.

Comment: You can use `@MapsId` if the FK column also is your primary key, or use `@NotFound(IGNORE)`, but that will essentially make the association eager i.e. it will always join/select the target to determine whether the field should be initialized to `null` or an entity.