# @OneToOne Nullable (optional=true) throws FetchNotFoundException in hibernate 6

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities

```
@Entity
class Parent(
    @Id 
    val id: Long,
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    val child: Child?,
}

@Entity
class Child(
    @Id 
    val id: Long,
    val someBasicField: Int
)
```

Parent and Child share same Primary key.

In hibernate 5 (5.6.14.Final) this setup works fine. Its have lazy loading. And it can be null, and child may not be exist.
Make attention to `optional = true`, and child declared as nullable.

But in hibernate 6 (6.2.9.Final), when you execute query with fetching child like

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = ["child"])
fun findById(id: Long): Parent?
```

If child does not exist, hibernate will throw

```
org.hibernate.FetchNotFoundException: Entity foo.bar.Child with identifier value `123` does not exist
```

which is actualy OK because as i mentioned earlier relation is specified as nullable and optional. Why this behaveior changed in hibernate 6? why its act like `optional=false`?

*Not working workarounds:*

- Solution with `@NotFound(action = IGNORE)` is not apliable, because you lose LAZY, and relation will always act as EAGER which i dont want.
- If i replace `@MapsId` with `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` exception will not trown anymore, but againg it will loose `LAZY` fetching, and will act as `EAGER`

Comment: does this solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784228/optional-one-to-one-mapping-in-hibernate